# How to prevent Kafka producer ids from expiring without producing?

Tags: apache-kafka

By default the broker setting `transactional.id.expiration.ms` is set to 7 days and this is the expiration time for producer ids too.
Can the expiration of the producer ids be prevented without producing to a topic?

Comment: What's the use-case?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Some services won't be used for an extended period and their first messages to be consumed will be missed and therefore data lost.

Comment: That's only determined by the log retention time, not producer/transaction id expiration

Answer (score 1):

you cannot prevent it from expiring as "transactional.id.expiration.ms" determines how long producer id and transactional id are valid.
however you can prevent client application from erroring out / crashing with error "InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id"

Upgraded the client libraries to 2.8.0
Using the new StreamsExceptionHandler, use REPLACE_THREAD in case of InvalidPidMappingException.
This causes the application to create a new thread and continue processing Event

issue- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13292?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17415251#comment-17415251